# Is there a downside to being in debt?

Tags: sid-meiers-simgolf

In Sid Meier's SimGolf, I fell into debt after spending all my money. However, I can still continue building my golf course and buying land. Spending money just puts me further into debt. Is there any reason I can't just stay in debt forever?

[image: Negative money]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After building my 3rd hole, I was no longer able to keep building if I didn't have enough money. Additionally, after the year ended I got a notification saying my course would be closed if I didn't achieve a positive cash flow within two years.